# Find data point generating Error in Perl code

Tags: perl, variables, runtime-error, warnings

I have a program in Perl that reads one line at a time from a data file and computes certain statistics for each line of data. Every now and then, while the program reads through my dataset, I get a warning about an `...uninitialized value...` and I would like to know which line of data generates this warning. 
Is there any way I can tell Perl to print (to screen or file) the data point that is generating the error?

Answer (score 4):

If your script prints one line for each input line, it would be simpler to see when the error occurs by flushing the standard error along with the output (making the message appear at the "right" point):

```
$| = 1;
```

That is, turn on the perl autoflush feature, as discussed in [How to flush output to the console?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=20590)

What (auto)flushing does:

- error messages are written to the predefined STDERR stream, normal printf's go to the (default) predefined STDOUT.
- data written on these streams is saved up by the system (under Perl's control) to write out in chunks (called "buffers") to improve efficiency.
- STDERR and STDOUT buffers are independent, and could be written line-by-line or by buffers (many characters, not necessarily lines).
- using autoflush tells Perl to modify its scheme for writing buffers so that their content is written via the operating system at the end of a print/printf call.
- normally STDERR is written line-by-line.  The command tells Perl to enable this feature for the current/default stream, i.e., STDOUT.
- doing that makes both of them write line-by-line, so that messages sent *close* in time via either appears *close* together in the output of your script.

Comment: To answer your question, my code reads in a line of values, computes certain statistics and writes them into an output file; then takes the next line from data file, reads it, etc.. I'm a little confused by what would 'flushing' do to my code: is it supposed to add the error message to my output file or is it supposed to print the line of data that causes the error on the screen while the program reads through the data file?

Comment: I have learned a great deal from you answer; I will now try to implement it into my code!

Answer (score 2):

Perl usually includes the file handle and line number in warnings by default; i.e.

```
>echo hello | perl -lnwe 'print $x'
Name "main::x" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $x in print at -e line 1, <> line 1.
```

So if you're doing the computation while reading, you get the appropriate warning.

Comment: But, doesn't this tell me the line in the code? I would like to know which line in the data set generates the error...

Comment: It should tell you both.  Notice my code produced 2 warns.  The first happened at compile time, so it only gave the line in the script (-e).  The second gave both the script ( -e line 1) and the file handle (<> line 1) since it happened while the <> was open and being read from.

Comment: I have not yet figured out why, in my case Perl only tells me the line of the code and not the one in the data set that generates the error: do you have any ideas/suggestions?